# Co-locating typescript code in next.js project

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, compilation, babeljs

I am working on a Next.js project, that I've initialized with `create next-app`.

Inside the project, I would like to co-locate some typescript code, which should run once a day in a node environment. My file structure is as such:

```
src
-components
-lib
-pages
```

I've co-located the node code inside `/lib`. All the files I am using are `.ts` files.

I would like to be able to run these files using `nodemon`, and I would like to be able to use es6 syntax such as `import` and `export`. To my understanding, I need to configure my `tsconfig.json` and a `.babelrc` file to do this.

Where can I find good templates for these files? I have a default `tsconfig.json`, but I don't want to change it as I do not want to interfere with my `Next.js` code.

Furthermore, if I were to use babel for the node code, how does babel actually run? Does it happen during compilation when I run `nodemon` or `node`?

What I've tried so far is:

1. I installed the `babel-node` dependencies locally to my project.
2. I added a `.babelrc` to my root with some typescript presets.
3. I set up a script in my `package.json` to run the `babel-node` command on my `index.ts` file.

But when I run the script, it gives me an error that I cannot use `import` outside of a module- I was under the impression this would be resolved by my `.babelrc` file.

Below is my current `tsconfig.json` and `.babelrc`.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "@": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```